# restrict special numbers for input

Tags: javascript, jquery, input, numbers, restriction

I want to restrict special numbers for input, so far I have restricted just symbols and text:

```
<input type="text" id="txtPageNumber" class="txtPageNumber" onkeyup="this.value = this.value.replace(/[^0-9\.]/g,'')" value="" />
```

but I want to let people to enter just special numbers, for example: from 1 to 16...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As you've tagged your question with jQuery, here's how you could use [jQuery validation plugin](http://docs.jquery.com/Plugins/Validation/Methods/range#range)

```
$("#myform").validate({
  rules: {
    txtPageNumber: {
      required: true,
      range: [1,16]
    }
  }
});
```

Comment: is there any easier way to achieve it?

Comment: In jQuery? I doubt it! That looks pretty concise. Do you have some additional requirements or constraints on the "ideal" solution?